# Generic in array and its warning message

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am still learning Java collection framework and how it works ....

it is said that we can't allocate size involving with a type parameter so when i wrote the following code

```
Stacks<card> stack = new Stacks[5]; // it causes a compiler warning
```

is there any way so that i can hide this warning ?

Comment: You reference the collections framework, yet you seem to be trying to instantiate an array. Are you sure you're not trying to do this: `Stack<Card> stack = new Stack<>()`?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you want to create a Stack array? Better to use:

```
Stack<Card> myStack = new Stack<Card>();
```